# Grep : Filtering Question

Tags: grep

I need to construct a regular expression that will filter a group of words that begins and ends with the same word. For example, `the life of the free` will output `the life of the` and `he was and he his the same` will output `he was and he`.  The two words have to be maximum 10 characters from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `grep` with extended Regular Expression:

```
$ echo "the life of the free" | grep -Eo "(\b[[:alnum:]]+\b)([[:blank:]]|[[:alnum:]]){1,10}\1"
the life of the

$ echo "he was and he his the same" | grep -Eo "(\b[[:alnum:]]+\b)([[:blank:]]|[[:alnum:]]){1,10}\1"
he was and he
```

Here `-E` means extended regexp, `-o` means only print the matched portion of the line, `\b` matches the word boundary, the character class `[[:alnum:]]` means all alphabetic (uppercase & lowercase) and numerical characters, `[[:blank:]]` means space or tab, `+` means one or more occurrences of the previous match, `{1,10}` the previous match can occur between 1 to a maximum of 10 times, `\1` means match the first matched group (expressed between first pair of parentheses) i.e. `\b[[:alnum:]]+\b`.

Answer (score 2):

With PCRE, one can do:

```
grep -Po '\b(\w+)\b.{1,10}\b\1\b'
```

- `-P` enables Perl-style regular expressions using PCRE.
- `-o` prints only the matched text.
- `\b` marks the word boundary
- `(\w+)` groups a match of word characters
- `.{1,10}` matches up to 10 characters and at least 1.
- `\1` refers to the group matched earlier.